# jTable still sorts numbers incorrectly after overriding getColumnClass method

Tags: java, sorting, jtable, numbers, integer

I am trying to make my jTable sort numbers but it still does not work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but everything seems alright.

My code:
    public static javax.swing.JTable jTable1;

```
public void fillMain() {

jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

//finalcolumns is a List<String> of all my column names
//types is List<Class> of classes of my columns


    DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[0][], new String[] {"testcolumn1", "testcolumn2", "testcolumn3"}) {
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            System.out.println("Class: " types.get(col).toString()); 
            //here it really returns the right column class (Integer.class)
            return types.get(col);
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return finalcolumns.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return finalcolumns.get(col);
        }
    };

jTable1.setModel(tm);
jTable1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

}
```

As I tagged inside the code, I am Overriding DefaultTableModel methods and the overriding works as it should, all methods that I Override returns proper values.

So it is like: TableModel says: "this column is Integer class and it contains integer objects so I sort it like a String".

Why it happens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching the problem correctly, but I suspect there may be an issue with the way you are initializing the table or with the finalColumns or types lists that are not shown.

A generalized way to implement getColumnClass is shown below.  This is based on the suggested implementation presented in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), but with an added check to protect against a table model with 0 rows:

```
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {

    Class retVal = Object.class;

    if(getRowCount() > 0)
        retVal =  getValueAt(0, col).getClass();

    return retVal;
}
```

If you replace your tm TableModel declaration/initialization with this snippet below, it should provide the behavior you seek.  You should just need to change how it populates the table data and columnHeaders.

```
Object[][] data = new Object[5][3];

data[0][0] = "word";
data[1][0] = "jive";
data[2][0] = "stuff";
data[3][0] = "word2";
data[4][0] = "abc";

data[0][1] = new Integer(410);
data[1][1] = new Integer(45);
data[2][1] = new Integer(456456);
data[3][1] = new Integer(4);
data[4][1] = new Integer(4);

String[] columnNames = new String[] {"testcolumn1", "testcolumn2"};

DefaultTableModel tm2 = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {

        Class retVal = Object.class;

        if(getRowCount() > 0)
            retVal =  getValueAt(0, col).getClass();

        return retVal;
    }

};
```

Hope this helps.